# scrolling position keeps going to top without me telling it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-masonry

I have a function that loads new items when I get close to the bottom of the page. It works great, the only issue is that when the new items load, then the scrolling position goes all the way back to the top, which is very messy and not what I want. Here is the function:

```
function loader(url) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $newPosts = $(data).filter(function(){
            return this.id === 'posts';
        }).children();
        $newPosts.hide();
            $wall.masonry('destroy');
            $('#posts').append($newPosts);
        $newPosts.each(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
            $wall.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.entry, .entry_photo',
                isAnimated : false
            });
    }).error(function(url) {
        alert('error');
    });
};
```

## [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajjaz/6/)

So as you can see, it jumps right back to the top and looks jagged. How can I prevent that? And why does it happen?

Comment: seems to me that the jsfiddle link is not showing the problem. can you fix it?

Comment: That jsfiddle is showing the problem for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that the call to `destroy` in masonry is the root of the issues here.

Use the `appended` method

```
$wall
  .append( $newPosts )
  .masonry( 'appended', $newPosts );
  .masonry( 'layout' );
```

Comment: Yes `$wall.masonry('appended',$newPosts);` that did the trick! thanks!

Comment: @RyanSaxe when I scroll down new content is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your scroll function with this scripts and see.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/ajjaz/7/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){  
    if ($('#posts').outerHeight() - $('body').scrollTop() - 420 <= 0) {
        loader(site);
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).scrollTop() }, 'fast');
        page += 1;
    }    
});
```

Comment: Try to change animate speed to fast?  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).scrollTop() }, 'fast');

Comment: I tried, I even tried changing it to 0, and it still was pretty jagged